Can there be a joint (with just tape) in HVAC control wire outside the unit?
I was having some problem with my AC condenser, it was having hard time starting.
I called this HVAC contractor, he came, did some testing and told me that the control wire which goes to the condenser is worn out (near the condenser unit, outside the building) and that is the reason it is not sending enough voltage to contactor, so he cut that wire where it comes out of the building and replaced that last stretch of the wire to the condenser unit , that did not solve my problem.
I had to call another company and they found something else as the problem and fixed it, and that solved the problem.
My question: First contractor replaced the last stretch with new wire and he twisted the wires together to join with old wire coming out of the building and he put tape on it. Is that right way to join this control wire according to electrical code? I know that this wire carries low voltage but I want to make sure it is done correctly.


Low voltage wires do not really have a code.  More of if it works good, does not work try something else.
